# Can't reinstall Virtualbox on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, vagrant

This morning vagrant suddenly does not serve http pages. I *VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Network Driver*. Then vagrant is now no working, looping through "connection reset".

I tried to uninstall VirtualBox on Control panel but it does not go away.

**How can I completely remove VirtualBox so I can reinstall the new version?**

Comment: Did you try to just install the new version?

Comment: yes the 5.2.2 windows

Comment: And you're still getting an error? I'm not sure what's actually up with the network adapter as you seem to be missing a few words in your sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like Revo Uninstaller.  Revo, for instance, helps you find the related files that weren't uninstalled with the built-in uninstaller, whether it failed mid-uninstall or if it just doesn't actually uninstall everything.

When I was a computer tech, I tried several "uninstaller" software, but I don't remember any of them working as well as Revo.  I'm not affiliated with them in any way, nor do I get paid to suggest their software, I just know it works.